Insert to mysql table with a column automatically has same value as another column
I has a mysql table with 2 int columns. The first column is auto_increment. Then, I want to insert whether a certain value or the value of the first column to the 2rd column.
For example
insert into tab(id,keyy) values (null, id);

I want this statement to insert a row with the id being the current ai number and the keyy the same as the id. Is there any simple way to do that?
Thank in advance.

There is a feature called Generated Columns in MySQL. You may want to lookup the documentation and see if it works for you.

I tried  "create table labels1(
rowId int primary key auto_increment,
labelId int as (rowId * 2) persistent);" bút got error "#1901 - Function or expression 'AUTO_INCREMENT' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of rowId"

Here are possible solutions: Error "generated Column cannot refer to auto-increment column " in MySQL Table and Two autoincrements columns or autoincrement and same value in other column.

Also, the error is expected. As per the MySQL documentation - "An AUTO_INCREMENT column cannot be used as a base column in a generated column definition.".

I can't imagine why anyone would want to do this , it would be helpful if you explained .the problem for which you think this is the solution

@prasad_ Thanks very much. The 2rd article you suggested answered my question perhap. It suggested call update  after insert immediately, or use max function, or query the a_i number from schema. But I'm still hoping there is another solution simpler than those.

@All I will update my real problem in the answer below

I have had a problem. I has a table storing "label" and its "labelId", it also has a primary auto increment column called "rowId". When update label, I don't update the row but add a new row with that labelId and new label text. When add new label, I also insert new row and just input the label text, and the labelId should get the value of the current rowId. That's it when adding new label. I have thought that there's a simple solution for this. Thank for reading.

What does select version() show?  There may be a very simple solution

@ysth It shows 10.6.19-MariaDB

on insert you create a new row but on update you create a new row cloning all the columns other than the columns to be updated? FROM the most recent row for that label?

@P.Salmon Ah, I want to add row update about 2 columns, 1 for label text and 1 for modified time, set to current time.You're right about updated from the most recent row

@P.Salmon The column labelId is the only one that I want not to update. That's enough for my problem

Note that since you only want labelId to be rowId when creating a new label, not when inserting a new row because a label was updated, you don't want to use a generated column, you just want labelId to default to rowId.
You can't do this with auto_increment, but you can do it if the id is set from a sequence:
create sequence label_sequence;
create table labels (
    rowId int not null primary key default next value for label_sequence,
    labelId int not null default rowId
);

Sequences are only available in mariadb, not mysql.
If you are using last_insert_id(), this will not work; last_insert_id is only available for auto_increment.

Thanks, your code works for me. But is it normal behavior of sequence that each insert command running it start from new value other than the old one plus 1. The first run it start at 1, the 2nd at 1001,, the 3rd at 2001. I run in phpmyadmin

That would happen if you restart the server each time, it will start with a fresh cache of 1000.  You can turn cache off for the sequence, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-sequence/

Actually, I want to generate new labelId(which not exists before) for new label, so I thought I could take it easily from auto increment column but it is not. Now, knowing sequence, I can directly create the labelId column to be default from the sequence :)

To sort the rows in your MySQL table by the score in the mark column, showing the highest scores first, you can use the ORDER BY clause. To sort from highest to lowest, use DESC.
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY mark DESC;
If you only want to see the top n rows with the highest scores, you can add the LIMIT clause
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY mark DESC
LIMIT n;
Replace n with the number of rows you want to retrieve. This will show the top n rows with the highest scores.

Thanks, I read your answer, but I ask about insert statement.
